# Colorbox Crashing When Viewed As Mobile App

Tags: iphone, mobile, colorbox

I have installed and configured the Colorbox Module for Drupal on my mobile site. Everything works correctly, except when a user opens the site from their homescreen in an iPhone. The Colorbox opens briefly, then closes. This does not occur when a user is viewing the mobile version of the site on their iPhone in Safari. It only happens after they have added it to their homescreen and view it through that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the following script was causing the error. This script prevents links from opening in Mobile Safari. https://gist.github.com/1042026

```
<script>(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>
```